# Tools Grayed Out in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

So is the grayed out tools only an issue for ASP pages, not ASP.NET? I'm reading all the solution ideas on StackOverflow regarding this issue, and I can't get any of them to work.

My tools work great on ASP.NET pages, but I cannot get them to work for a classic ASP page...seems odd...

Anyone else running into this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the Designer and managed controls in the Toolbox?

Comment: Sorry, I got the term wrong. Yes, you are correct. I am not able to use anything in the Toolbox panel.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_vsasp.asp the controls you were using were ASP.NET controls, they are not available in classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP is a completely different animal than ASP.NET, no code behind among (many, many, many) other things.  Your controls aren't going to work there.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm new to ASP and ASP.NET. I did not know of this difference. That changes a lot with what I'm working with, but it totally helps to know this. Thank you for your help. This answers my question. :)